# Is it possible to set specific package name for generated openApi spec file

Tags: java, spring, gradle, openapi-generator

In our project (java/spring/gradle stack), we are using openApi specs. We have a couple of services and specs for them. Also, we have common modules that duplicate in each spec. We moved those common modules to a separate spec file and include them in others. For instance:

```
specific_project1:
   openapi:
      spec.yaml
      common_modules.yaml
   build.gradle
```

The `spec.yaml` has the next code:

```
openapi: 3.0.0
info:
  version: 0.0.1
paths:
  /specific/post:
    post:
      requestBody:
        context:
          application/json:
             schema:
               $ref: "common_modules.yaml#/components/schemas/TestModule"
```

and the `common_modules.yaml` the next:

```
openapi: 3.0.0
info:
  version: 0.0.1
components:
  schemas:
    TestModule:
      type: object
      properties:
        value:
          type: string
```

As the result, we need that `spec.yaml` to be generated with package name `com.specific.project1`, `common_modules.yaml` is generated with package name `com.common.modules` and the generated java class that is generated from `spec.yaml` has an import for `TestModule` with package `com.common.modules` in imports.

Comment: Please include your Gradle file which should include the plugins configuration you are using to generate files.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We found the solution on how to refer to the same object. We published `TestModule` as a separate project with its own package and in other projects, we used the `importMappings` configuration to define the proper package name for the object.

```
importMappings = [
   TestModule: "com.common.modules.TestModule"
]
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible.

First add openapi plugin to build.grade if you have not done so.

```
plugins { 
 
       id "org.openapi.generator" version "4.3.0"
}
```

You'll get access to openApiGenerate Task,

This can be modified like this for example:

```
openApiGenerate {
    generatorName = "jaxrs-jersey"
    inputSpec = "$rootDir/spec-v1.yaml".toString()
    outputDir = "$rootDir/".toString()
    apiPackage = "name.of.api.package.rest.server.v1.api"
    invokerPackage = "name.of.api.package.rest.server.v1.invoker"
    modelPackage = "name.of.api.package.rest.server.v1.model"
    configOptions = [
        library: "jersey2"
    ]
}
```

here is the link for all the possible modification you can do related to spring for example https://github.com/OpenAPITools/openapi-generator/blob/master/docs/generators/spring.md

and for the full list of generators: https://github.com/OpenAPITools/openapi-generator/tree/master/docs/generators

In order to use 2 yaml files in a single project here is what you have to do:

```
task common(type: org.openapitools.generator.gradle.plugin.tasks.GenerateTask){
generatorName = "spring"
inputSpec = "$rootDir//schema/common.yaml".toString()
outputDir = "$rootDir/generated".toString()
apiPackage = "com.abc.code.generated.controller"
modelPackage = "com.abc.code.generated.model"
configOptions = [
        dateLibrary: "java8"
]
systemProperties = [
    invoker : "false", 
    generateSupportingFiles: "true"
]
additionalProperties = [
    interfaceOnly : "true",
]
```

And you can leave the openApiGenerate for the spec.yaml
But make sure to add

```
compileJava.dependsOn common , tasks.openApiGenerate
```

So you'll execute both of them.
Hope this is of help.

Comment: thanks for your response. Do you know if it is possible to specify different packages for related files? For instance, I have the next structure:
`spec.yaml`
`common.yaml`
. `spec` file has a reference on the `common` file. I need the `spec` file to be generated with package `com.spec` and the `common` file with package `com.common`.

Comment: Yes , actually its possible in multiple ways , i ll update my answer .

Comment: thank you very much for your update. But still, the open question is about imports in that 2 files. With your config we will generate just 2 files with different packages, but how to define the right import with the right package? I'll update my question with more details to be clear.